# Is it possible to acquire less than a degree accuracy in iOS compass heading?

Tags: ios, compass-geolocation, magnetometer, heading

Basically I want to know the direction iPhone is pointing with high precision, I tried CLLocationManager: the problem is the CLHeading.magneticHeading returns a double for example 36.44323 but then when I start turning the device, CLLocationManager only updates the direction  when it reaches 1 degree, so the numbers read like this : 36.44323, 37.44323, 38.44323 and so on. Is it possible to have more accuracy?

Comment: Have you set the `desiredAccuracy` on `CLLocationManager` to `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation`? This will utilize more than just the magnetometer (such as gyro).  Maybe this will get you better accuracy?

Comment: Yes tested that but the result is the same, I've done also these with no luck: 1- setting headingFilter to less than 1 and also setting it to kCLHeadingFilterNone , 2- make a separate thread to read CLLocationManager data manually between updates and 3- to call stopUpdatingHeading at the end of didUpdateHeading method and turning it on again using a separate thread but the result is not reliable, as it takes a while for results to become stable.

Answer (score 5):

Set `CLLocationManager` `headingFilter` to `kCLHeadingFilterNone` or anything less than the default 1 degree.

Comment: this will not increase the precision, it will only update more frequently

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about the accuracy but are interested in the small changes in direction then you may want to look at `CMMotionManager`. It was a property (`deviceMotion`) which will allow you to get the `attitude` of the device, in particularly the `yaw`. By recording the difference (say `x`) between the yaw & magnetic heading on each heading update you can get the approximate heading in between updates as `yaw + x`. You will receive timelier updates from `CMMotionManager` because you can set the `deviceMotionUpdateInterval` yourself.

If I remember correctly the `yaw` value is returned in radians between -pi and pi so you will need to convert back to degrees when calculating `x` as `CLLocationManager` will return the magnetic heading is degrees (0 to 360).

You will probably want to make adjustments for device orientation as well. The compass returns heading data from the top of the device so if you are in landscapeLeft you will need to subtract 90° from the heading value, landscapeRight you will need to add 90° to the heading value and portraitUpsideDown will require an adjustment of 180°.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of, no.

And don't confuse accuracy with correctness; just because it says 36.44323 doesn't mean it's accurate to 5 decimal places, the error bounds on that value might be ±1 degree :(

I don't think that the compass on an iPhone has high enough precision to say with any real confidence which direction you are pointing to the accuracy you want. Sorry!

Comment: I don't care about the correctness of the number but rather i'm interested in very small change in the direction of the device, There should be a reason the resulting number is double rather than integer,

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Gyro if you need more accuracy. The device motion data from CoreMotion should help you with that. Compass really isn't accurate enough.